# winforms leave event and textchanged

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm new to learning winforms and i'm stuck on the following problem and I do not think what I have done is the correct way, so any help would be appreciated.

I have 4 textboxes such as the following

```
private void txtBxPlayer1Bid_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            txtBxFundsAvialable.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(txtBxFundsAvialable.Text) - Convert.ToInt32(txtBxPlayer1Bid.Text)).ToString();
        }
```

The 5th textbox txtBxFundsAvialable simple subtract the value of txtBxPlayer1Bid from txtBxFundsAvialable.

In designer.cs I have

```
this.txtBxPlayer1Bid.Leave += new System.EventHandler(this.txtBxPlayer1Bid_TextChanged);
```

The problem I have is, if I have 100 in txtBxFundsAvialable and enter 10 in txtBxPlayer1Bid the value in txtBxFundsAvialable should be 90, but txtBxPlayer1Bid etc seem to go into a loop and the value in txtBxFundsAvialable becomes 60. 4 textboxes X 10.

This happens for any of the 4 textboxes

The only way I can solve the problem is to set the values of the 4 textboxes to 0 in the txtBxFundsAvialable_TextChanged as shown below.

```
 private void txtBxFundsAvialable_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Convert.ToInt32(txtBxPlayer1Bid.Text) > 4 || (Convert.ToInt32(txtBxPlayer2Bid.Text)> 4 || (Convert.ToInt32(txtBxPlayer3Bid.Text)> 4) || (Convert.ToInt32(txtBxPlayer2Bid.Text)> 4)))
            {
                txtBxPlayer1Bid.Text    = "0";
                txtBxPlayer2Bid.Text    = "0";
                txtBxPlayer3Bid.Text    = "0";
                txtBxPlayer4Bid.Text    = "0";
             }
        }
```

Is what I'm doing the correct way, as stated at the beginning, I'm new to winforms and it a canny leanning curve

Comment: Why do you listen to the `Leave` event?

Comment: Hi @YoryeNathan looking for help on forums and here and it seems this was the correct way i.e http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16619225/why-my-textbox-textchanged-event-gets-fired-after-i-enter-only-one-character-i

Comment: Listen to the `TextChanged` event. It's just so logically correct.

Comment: Either do what @YoryeNathan said or make a button. I didn't quite understand what you were trying to do in this script. Also, why do you have 4 different textboxes for a simple subtract?

Comment: Hi @Aradmey the 4 textboxes can have different values, the user does not have to enter a value in three of them, but at least 1 must have a value. I was thinking about a button, but was trying to do it without a button. Don't learn unless you try :)

Comment: There is an obvious logical error in your code, changing the textbox text cannot subtract an amount from a total.  The user types `1` and you subtract 1, then `0` and you subtract 10.  So you've subtracted 11, that's not correct of course.  Thinking about how to fix that is a mental exercise that's important to do by yourself if you want to become a programmer.

Comment: Hi @HansPassant not sure what you mean, if I have txtBxFundsAvialable.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(txtBxFundsAvialable.Text) - Convert.ToInt32(txtBxPlayer1Bid.Text)).ToString(); and the value in txtBxFundsAvialable is 100, if I enter 1 in txtBxPlayer1Bid then the value in txtBxFundsAvialable becomes 99.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a simple code with 2 textboxes that get values and a textbox with the result. Updates with `TextChanged`event. Try to use it to fix your code..

```
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            int num1 = Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text), num2 = Int32.Parse(textBox2.Text);
            textBox3.Text = (num1 - num2).ToString();
        }
        catch { }
    }

    private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1_TextChanged(sender, e);
    }
```

### EDIT

Try this code and link any of your "bid" textboxes to this function. `textbox1` in this code is equivalent to your "available" textbox.

```
    private void textBox_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            int num = Int32.Parse(((TextBox)sender).Text), available = Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            textBox1.Text = (available - num).ToString();
        }
        catch { }
    }
```

Comment: Hi @Aradmey quick question, what version of VS are you using, I have just tried your code example and get the following error when entering 3 Input string was not in a correct format. Also as stated earlier, when using TextChanged it only allows entering 1 character before fireing.

Comment: I am using VS 2010. I just understood what you're trying to script and have made something work with `Leave` event. Will edit my answer in a moment

Comment: Check the new code I posted above. And if you want to clear the textbox from text after it leaves too, use this line: `((TextBox)sender).Text = "";`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how `.Leave` operates. Try to use `.TextChanged` or whatever the equivalent in WinForms.

All four (or even five) text boxes should use same event callback method.

Here is what you can do in that method:

```
private void txtBx_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double player1 = 0, player2 = 0, player3 = 0, player4 = 0, total = 0;
    if (int.TryParse(txtBxPlayer1Bid.Text, out player1)
         && int.TryParse(txtBxPlayer2Bid.Text, out player2)
         && int.TryParse(txtBxPlayer3Bid.Text, out player3)
         && int.TryParse(txtBxPlayer4Bid.Text, out player4)
         && int.TryParse(txtBxFundsAvialable.Text, out total)

    {
        total = player1 + player2 + player3 + player4;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Alexey .TextChanged only allows 1 char before firing, that was why I was using leave.

Comment: that is right, that's will constantly update the total as you type. otherwise you can add a button to trigger calculation as @Aradmey suggested.